# Protractor test structure

Tags: protractor

Protractor test structure:

```
- Spec.js
  -- Personal Info
  -- Address Info
  -- Billing Info
```

Spec.js calls Personal Info, Address Info, Billing Info sequentially. Till Personal Info section is filled out, wont be able to go to Address Info section and so on.

I want to fill out same application using different data sets. In Conf.js how can I call same Spec.js multiple times with different data set?

I have tried Count: '2' option in Conf.js. But it runs same data set in both browsers and then the next data set in both browsers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `Spec.js` different times. You should implement this logic in `Spec.js` file. So, in `Conf` you will call `Spec` as usual once. But there will be implementation that will run the same but several times with new data. How to implement that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using forEach on a json object for each of its property .So,That for each property in JSON object the tests gets repeated.OBJECT (i.e) obj1 should have different keys and the test data for execution.

```
Object.keys(obj1).forEach((value) => {

var a = `obj1.${value}`;

describe(`${value}`, function () {

    it('Should .............', function () {
       // test

    })
   })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using jasmine data-providers https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider

This will allow to re-use the same spec with different data sets. The data set is normally an object or array of objects containing your data.